# Redux-tookit: Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

> Error type: Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the
> argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are
> reducers.

I am trying to add a Store and my app is failing. I don't understand where the error is coming from. Can someone point out my error and how to fix it?

store

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducers from './reducers';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducers,
});

export default store;
```

reducer

```
import handleCart from './handleCart';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducers = combineReducers({
  handleCart,
});

export default rootReducers;
```

```
const cart = [];

const handleCart = (state = cart, action) => {
  const product = action.payload;
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADDITEM:
      // Check product exist
      const exist = state.find(x => x.id === product.id);
      if (exist) {
        return state.map(x =>
          x.id === product.id ? {...x, qty: x.qty + 1} : x,
        );
      } else {
        const product = action.payload;
        return [
          ...state,
          {
            ...product,
            qty: 1,
          },
        ];
      }
      break;
    case REMOVEITEM:
      const exist1 = state.find(x => x.id === product.id);
      if (exist1.qty === 1) {
        return state.filter(x => x.id !== exist1.id);
      } else {
        return state.map(x =>
          x.id === product.id ? {...x, qty: x.qty - 1} : x,
        );
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

Comment: What's `handleCart`? Show the code

Comment: i added ```handleCart```

Comment: Did you export it?

Comment: yes I did export it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see only a couple overt issues in the `handleCart` reducer function code, either could be cause for throwing an exception. It seems the `handleCart` reducer function is missing returning state in the default case. The `REMOVEITEM` case also incorrectly assumes `exist` is defined and accesses a `qty` property of a potentially undefined object. Remember that `Array.prototype.find` returns `undefined` when no matching element is found in the array.

Make sure the `handleCart` is default exported so it can be imported to create the root reducer.

```js
const cart = [];

const handleCart = (state = cart, action) => {
  const product = action.payload;

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADDITEM: {
      // Check product exist
      const exist = state.find(x => x.id === product.id);

      if (exist) {
        return state.map(x =>
          x.id === product.id ? { ...x, qty: x.qty + 1 } : x,
        );
      }
      return [...state, { ...product, qty: 1 }];
    }

    case REMOVEITEM: {
      const exist = state.find(x => x.id === product.id);

      if (exist) {
        // item exists, update quantity
        if (exist.qty === 1) {
          return state.filter(x => x.id !== exist1.id);
        } else {
          return state.map(x =>
            x.id === product.id ? { ...x, qty: x.qty - 1 } : x,
          );
        }
      }
      // item didn't exist, just return current state
      return state;
    }

    default:
      // No action to do, return current state
      return state;
  }
};

export default handleCart;
```

You are using redux-toolkit, why are you not creating state slice? Here's a similar implementation using `createSlice`. This allows you to write the reducer functions using mutable updates instead of needing to shallow copy all the parts of the state that are being updated.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = [];

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      const product = state.find(product => product.id === action.payload.id);

      if (product) {
        product.qty++;
      } else {
        state.push({ ...action.payload, qty: 1 });
      }
    },
    removeItem: (state, action) => {
      const product = state.find(product => product.id === action.payload.id);

      if (product) {
        product.qty--;
        if (product.qty === 0) {
          state.filter(product => product.id !== action.payload.id);
        }
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { addItem, removeItem } = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```